# Node-Red install fails

Tags: node.js, npm, node-red

I am trying to install node-red on my new system and for some reason it is failing with the following error:

```
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@8.19.3
2 info using node@v18.13.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 6ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 6ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Alex\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
14 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load Completed in 12ms
18 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 12ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 1ms
20 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
21 verbose title npm install node-red
22 verbose argv "install" "--global" "--unsafe-perm" "node-red"
23 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
24 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
25 timing npm:load:display Completed in 3ms
26 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs
27 verbose logfile C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-22T11_59_29_047Z-debug-0.log
28 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 13ms
29 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
30 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
31 timing npm:load Completed in 30ms
32 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
33 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files
34 silly logfile done cleaning log files
35 timing idealTree:init Completed in 4ms
36 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 1ms
37 silly idealTree buildDeps
38 silly fetch manifest node-red@*
39 silly placeDep ROOT node-red@ OK for:  want: *
40 timing idealTree:#root Completed in 133177ms
41 timing idealTree:node_modules/node-red Completed in 1ms
42 timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 133179ms
43 timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 1ms
44 timing idealTree Completed in 133185ms
45 timing command:install Completed in 133194ms
46 verbose type system
47 verbose stack FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/node-red failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6810:1923:443
47 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:130:14)
47 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
47 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:496:9)
47 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:525:35)
47 verbose stack     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
47 verbose stack     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
47 verbose stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
48 verbose cwd C:\Users\Alex
49 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22621
50 verbose node v18.13.0
51 verbose npm  v8.19.3
52 error code ETIMEDOUT
53 error syscall connect
54 error errno ETIMEDOUT
55 error network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/node-red failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6810:1923:443
56 error network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
56 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
56 error network
56 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
56 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
57 verbose exit 1
58 timing npm Completed in 133301ms
59 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1674388769144
60 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1674388769150
61 verbose code 1
62 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
62 error     C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-22T11_59_29_047Z-debug-0.log
```

I already deleted any proxies

```
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete http-proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
```

Can anybody think of anything else that might be wrong?

I am running Windows 11 and used the docs here https://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/windows

Thank you everyone :)

Alex

Comment: Do you have a function IPv6 network on the machine you are using? What do you get if you visit https://ipv6-test.com/

Comment: @hardillb: Why do I need a functioning IPv6 to install node-red? I am still using the same provider as I did 1 year ago when I first installed it.

According to ipv6-test.com IPv6 is "supported", type "native", SLAAC "no", ICMP "Filtered" and Hostname "none".

Comment: I asked because if you read the npm error is failing to connect to the IPv6 address for the npm registry. This has nothing to do with Node-RED, it works fail to install ANY npm package

Comment: The test results imply that you have been assigned a IPv6 address but do not have a valid route. You need to either fix your IPv6 set up or disable it. (Configuring your windows IPv6 set up is a question for Super User not Stack Overflow)